# Div Cleared When Page Fully Loads

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a JavaScript & Ajax to make a php call to return data from my database.  The call returns the data as it should, but when the page fully loads the `<div>` tags value is cleared.

What do I need to change in my syntax so that the div tag retains the value `echo` from the php file?  I checked the Console and it is only showing page load info and nothing related to this issue (at least not that I saw).

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
<div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="padding-top: 10px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="MakeQuery()" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhttp;
function MakeQuery()
{
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} 
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){ if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status==200)
    { document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText; } }
     xhttp.open("GET", "SQLQuery.php", true); 
     xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: That’s because you neglected to prevent the actual form submit (go research how to do that), so the browser submits the form and displays the response from the server as a new document.

Comment: (Or, alternatively, do not use a _submit_ button to trigger your script functionality in the first place.)

Comment: All that I have found is that I could use the button as a submit or reset.  I do not want it to be a reset, seeming I do not want it to be a submit either.

Comment: Use type="button"

Comment: @gRaWEty - this leaves the button highlighted as if it is constantly being clicked.  Is there a way to return the button to "normal" after clicking?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh for me it is returning back to normal.

Comment: @gRaWEty - I see now, the button stays highlighted until I click somewhere else on the page.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh on which browser you are getting this?

Comment: _“this leaves the button highlighted as if it is constantly being clicked”_ – it is in the `:focus` state, and usually the browser default stylesheet has rules to format buttons differently in that state. If you don’t like those, then overwrite them via your own stylesheet.

Comment: @gRaWEty - chrome.

Comment: @CBroe - ah thank you for giving me a place to start searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to prevent the actual form submit before using AJAX:

```js
var xhttp;

function MakeQuery(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Cancel form submit, use AJAX

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "SQLQuery.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: This works, but also leaves the button highlighted.  Is there a way to return the button to "normal" after clicking?  It remains highlighted until I click somewhere else on the page.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Yes, you blur focus on the button like so document.getElementById("buttonid").blur(). 

Or you can pass the button "this" context as parameter the use blur on it.

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur